# fit theoretical spectrum to simulated one

Tags: matlab, power-spectral-density, optimization

I have a bunch of simulated time series, for which I can compute the power spectrum. Generally, the simulated power spectrum can be sketched as follows:

[image]

I now aim to calculate the features of the theoretical power spectrum. The theoretical power spectrum can be represented by:

$$ S_{th}=\frac{4\left(L/U_{hub}\right)}{\left(1+6f\left(L/U_{hub}\right)\right)^{5/3}} $$

where

$$ L = constant\ length\ scale $$
$$ U_{hub} = constant\ speed $$
$$ f = frequency\ vector $$

Given `Uhub` and `f` (they are "environtmental variables"), the theoretical power spectrum will approach, within a certain tolerance, the simulated one only for a certain defined value of `L`. This procedure will lead to the following figure:

[image]

Therefore, I am interested in developing a method which allows for the extrapolation of the right `L` value.

I have been thinking of using `lsqcurvefit`. Up to now I used it this way:

```
function p_theo = ps_th(x,f)
 L = x(1);
 Uhub = x(2);
 exp = 5/3;
 C = (L/Hub);
 f_x = 6.*f.*C;
 p_theo = 4*C./((1 + f_x).^exp);
end

lsqcurvefit(@ps_th,[330;Uhub],f,ps_sim)
```

But I am evidently using `lsqcurvefit` improperly, since only `L` is driving the optimization and `Uhub` must stay fixed.

Can anyone shed light on this problem?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Did it run and give you bad results? Did it provide an error? Note that optimizing for the right value of $L$ is equivalent to optimizing for the right value of $\frac{L}{U_{hub}}$ if $U_{hub}$ is a constant known *a priori*. So, you can instead solve for the optimal ratio instead, then calculate what $L$ would be.

Comment: can you average multiple spectra to get a closer approximation to start?

Comment: @endolith: yes I can

Comment: To restate @JasonR's point, in your equation, $L$ and $U_{hub}$ are not independent variables.  Only $C$ is.

Comment: I can't understand this program,can you send me full code of Power Spectrum Density.
I want that my result should be look like above fig.
So,please send me full code to my mail-id- bappa.ism@gmail.com Thanking you
Bappa Mukherjee
Student of Applied Geophysics.
I.S.M. Dhanbad-826004.
India.

Comment: I didn't use the function you talk about but I would suggest you replace
L/U with r since you don't have a single solution in your case